# How can I modify the SpeakHere sample app to record in mono format on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, audio-recording, audioqueue

I am new to iPhone. Could you please help me to modify the SpeakHere app from Apple to record in mono format. What should I have to set for `mChannelsPerFrame` and what else should I set?

I already change some part for record on linearPCM WAVE format.

Here is [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) to speakHere.

Here is what I think they allow me to change but I don't quite understand on sound:

```
void ChangeNumberChannels(UInt32 nChannels, bool interleaved)
                // alter an existing format
    {
        Assert(IsPCM(), "ChangeNumberChannels only works for PCM formats");
        UInt32 wordSize = SampleWordSize(); // get this before changing ANYTHING
        if (wordSize == 0)
            wordSize = (mBitsPerChannel + 7) / 8;
        mChannelsPerFrame = nChannels;
        mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        if (interleaved) {
            mBytesPerPacket = mBytesPerFrame = nChannels * wordSize;
            mFormatFlags &= ~kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
        } else {
            mBytesPerPacket = mBytesPerFrame = wordSize;
            mFormatFlags |= kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use audio queues ? Have you have had a look at AVAudioFramework for AVAudioRecorder ?

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone you will only be able to record in mono.

You shouldn't need to do anything to set this up in the SpeakHere example. It's done automatically. For example in `AQRecorder::SetupAudioFormat`:

```
size = sizeof(mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame);
XThrowIfError(AudioSessionGetProperty(  kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareInputNumberChannels, 
                &size, 
                &mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame), "couldn't get input channel count");
```

That gets the supported hardware input channels and sets it as an ivar. Elsewhere, the buffer size calculations will factor that in.