# iPhone SpeakHere Example recording on 1 channel

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

SpeakHere compiles fine, but only displays and uses a single (1) channel for recording input.  Is there a limitation to the iPhone 4 being a single channel mic and not using two channels? I can't seem to see where it will record with two channels.  Anyone have any suggestions?
It is a great example of audio programming concepts, but need some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check other questions posted related to speakhere, there are many related questions related to the same you are asking. Check the answer section of the following question :-
[How can I modify the SpeakHere sample app to record in mono format on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255846/how-can-i-modify-the-speakhere-sample-app-to-record-in-mono-format-on-iphone)